# How to list all the topics in all groups with total count of messages in each topic with single kafka command?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to list all topics from all group ids with total number of messages in each topic but couldn't find such command anywhere. Tried the below 2 commands but expecting the results of the below commands in a single command. Please help.

Command 1:(To list all topics in Kafka server)

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Command 2:(To know the count of total messages in a topic in Kafka server)

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list 0.0.0.0:6667 --topic topicname --time -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a kafka command that can do what you want. However, you can achieve this with basic shell scripting. This command should do the job :

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list | while read x; do ./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $x --time -1; done
```

Tested with kafka 0.10.2 running on Linux.

Comment: may be I should agree to what you said here, even till now I didn't find for what exactly I'm looking. Hope Apache will come up with such feature in future.